# Reference required to assembly System.Runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-api, google-drive-api

I am integrating google drive api in my .net application. It works fine with when i created new project in Visual Studio 2012.
But I am facing with issues when i am trying to integrate it with already developed application. The error is :

> Compiler Error Message: BC30007: Reference required to assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the base class
>   'System.Object'. Add one to your project.

I have included dlls in my bin folder. I can see visual studio is picking up namespaces for included dlls.

I need to know what exactly this error message means and how to fix it.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: did you use the NuGet package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/    Does your project target framework Net 4.5?

Comment: I install Nuget Package on new project i created from scratch but on already build application i added reference to dlls

Comment: sounds like you are missing the reference to System.Runtime

Comment: Yes target framework is 4.5

Comment: then just add the reference to system runtime you must have missed that one.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on. When i am going to Add reference to solution on top of that pop up, it says "Targetting .Net Framework 2.0"

Comment: but my web.cong says httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  And  compilation targetFramework="4.5"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124180/discussion-between-anjum-and-daimto).